# Selenium prevent redirect

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Does selenium automatic follow redirects? Because it seems that the webdriver isn't loading the page I requested.
And when it does automatic follow the redirects is there any possibility to prevent this?

ceddy

Comment: Selenium is just using browser, so behaviour would be the same as in browser that do redirects

Answer (score 1):

No, Selenium drives the browser like a regular user would, which means redirects are followed when requested by the web application via either a 30X HTTP status or when triggered by javascript.
I suggest you consider a legitimate bug in the application if you consider it problematic when it happens to users.